# Cosine Similarity PHP

Tags: php, cosine-similarity

I want to calculate the cosine similarity between 1 (ID1) and 3 (ID1) in PHP, similarly for 1 and 4, 3 and 4. formula would be something like this:

> similarity = (1.1 * 3.1 + 1.4 * 3.4)/(((1.1)^2+(1.3)^2+(1.4)^2)^0.5)(((3.1)^2+  (3.4)^2)^0.5) = (4*4+8*4)/(((16+16+64)^0.5)(16+16)^0.5))

My dataset looks like this:

```
ID1    ID2    Value  
1      1       4     
1      3       4     
1      4       8     
3      1       4     
3      4       4    
4      1       8     
4      3       4
```

Is there any code for calculating a cosine similarity in PHP for this?

Comment: [Cosine Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) is basic and looks nothing like your formula ... can you share more light and break it furder how the values relate to ID1 , ID2 and Value

Comment: Each value in ID1 represent a vector and ID2 represents the corresponding parts if i.e. 1.1 1.3 1.4 is a vector, the values after the dot is in ID2 for 1. Therefore 1 of ID1 is a vector. So I am comparing corresponding values of 1 and 3 (taking them as A and B vectors resp.). So cosine similarity is the same as given in the wiki.

Answer (score 4):

The formula is common in math, regardless of programming language.

If you have two vectors of length n:

```
u = (u1, u2, ...., un) and v = (v1, v2, ...., vn)
```

Then the cosine similarity (aka dot product) is:

```
u1*v1 + u2*v2 + .... + un*vn
_____________________________
     len(u) * len(v)
```

where `len(u) = sqrt(u1*u1 + u2*u2 + .... + un*un)`; similarly for `len(v)`

Comment: Yes but I have large dataset. How should I loop through so that I can calculate the similarity between each Id1 values and at the same time the code be optimal?

Comment: You asked for the formula.  Now you're assuming that it's sub-optimal?  You didn't even understand it a moment ago.  Should be possible to parallelize like crazy.

Comment: I have already written the formula in my question. My question clearly asks for a code not formula. Please read the question first.

Comment: if you know the formula, you should be able to create the code... it's just comparing elements of the same indices of two arrays.